# How to create % discount code for ENTIRE cart subtotal?

Tags: shopping-cart, discount, price-rules, magento-1.14

How do I create a discount code for the ENTIRE value of a shopping cart, with multiple items in it?

By default, the "percentage of product price discount" function applies a % discount ONLY to the first line item in your basket. I need to offer the discount on the ENTIRE basket value, even if there are multiple items in it. This discount can be applied to ANY product, there are no category or price restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make an pricerule for the basket and set the right conditions for it to target the whole basket.

it seams you have made it wrong if its only targeting one item.

this link explain the whole use of price rules - http://www.demacmedia.com/magento-commerce/shopping-cart-price-rules-in-magento-walk-through/

Comment: Hi. Sorry, but that's really not helpful.

Comment: give us the information on how you have made you pricerule

Comment: - Specific coupon
- Coupon code
- Uses per coupon: 9999
- Uses per customer: 5

Conditions: None

Action: 

- Apply: Percent of Product price discount
- Discount Amount: 10
- Maximum Qty Discount is Applied To: 0
- Discount Qty Step (Buy X): 0
- Apply to Shipping Amount
- Free Shipping: No
- Stop Further Rules Processing: no
- Add Reward Points: 0

Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions (leave blank for all items): Blank.

Comment: [Image of the Actions screen](http://imgur.com/f3hWSR2).

Answer (score 0):

You will want to create a shopping cart price rule.
This rule should be setup to discount x% off any item.  This will then provide you the results you are asking about.  A discount off all items in the cart.

If you want to apply the discounts so that everyone see's them on the website in search results, product pages, categories, etc.. You'll want to use the Catalog price rules.

These sections can be found under:

Promotions > Shopping Cart Price Rules
and
Promotions > Catalog Price Rules

These two sections can be configured in a myriad of ways, and the interactions between both can get very, very complex.  If you need help drop me a line.